# Xpath option with class, then value

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following html bit :

```
<select class="custom" id="pa_size" name="attribute_pa_size">
<option value="">Choose an option…</option>
<option value="7" class="active">7</option><
option value="8" class="active">8</option>
<option value="9" class="active">9</option>
</select>
```

What I want is to just get the values, not the Select option. I could do

```
$nodes = $xpath->query("//select[@id='pa_size']/option/@value");
        foreach ($nodes as $href=>$value){
        echo $value->textContent.'<br/>';
        }
```

And that reveals a blank, (since first option has no value), but it's not what I want. I mean I can work with it no problem, put it in an array and then split or even do a numeric preg_match. But what's bugging me is that the second i change it to `$xpath->query("//select[@id='pa_size']/option[class='active']/@value"` it breaks. I want to know why and how to fix this, searched SO and besides reversing the quotes (which = no go), i ve found nothing on it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to put `@` at the beginning of `class` attribute name here :

```
//select[@id='pa_size']/option[class='active']/@value
```

Above xpath tries to find `option` node having *child node* `class` -instead of *attribute* named `class`- equals "active". The xpath should've been :

```
//select[@id='pa_size']/option[@class='active']/@value
```

Comment: The faster I get the being dumb part over the closer I get to being smart. Thank you for your help. Literally spent 40 mins over this.

Comment: I slept on it and tried again as soon as I woke up. unfortunately, even with @ added, still no-go. is it working for you? do I need additional libraries? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not experienced with PHP, but the xpath seems to work fine for me in PHP too : http://missingbrackets.com/codepad/editor/vhRTeI